# Using Regex to extract line numbers of GOTOs/GOSUBs

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to extract GOTOs/GOSUBs line numbers from BASIC code. I intend to use NodeJS to manage the matches (so it's JS-flavoured Regex).

I'm doing tests using regex101.com (see here https://regex101.com/r/SaZuue/2 ) and I'm pretty close to what I want:

- extract `GOTO ###` as `["GOTO", " ", "###"]`
- extract `GOSUB ###` as `["GOSUB", " ", "###"]`
- extract `IF (cond) THEN ###` as `["THEN", " ", "###"]`
- extract `ON ERR GOTO #, ##, ###` as `["GOTO", " ", "#", ", ", "##", ", ", "###"]`
- same as above but with `ON ERR GOSUB`
- deal with the fact that spaces between `GOTO`, `GOSUB`, `THEN` and `,` are optional or can be multiple and in all cases return the exact number of spaces indicated.

So far I have come up with the following regex:

`/(GOTO|GOSUB|THEN)(\s*)(\d+)(?:(\s*,\s*)(\d+))*/ig`

Testing on:

`100 ON ERR GOTO 10000, 30,   200, 10,800: GOSUB 20: IF A THEN 10: GOTO30: GOTO  50`

All the matching groups are OK except for the `ON ERR GOTO` which returns only the first and last numbers (10000 & 800) and not the others.

What am I missing ? Thanks :)

Comment: JS regex does not support repeated captures, only the last value is kept. So, the best approach here is to [capture all the numbers](https://regex101.com/r/dPDLqD/1), and then split the Group 4 with `/\s*,\s*/` regex (and filter out empty values, if necessary). Pure regex solution is not possible here.

Comment: Argh ! Dammit ! Thanks anyway !

Comment: Note that some flavours of BASIC allow to put a line number into a variable: `A$=10:GOTO A$`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, yes I know :-) but I don't plan to support this feature because the value of `A$` could change during code execution and it would mean parsing the whole code behaviour which is beyond the scope of what 
I intend to do... (or more exactly beyond my needs, foi de Gloubi Boulga !)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to have an arbitrary number of captures with a regex, and there is no way to access multiple captures within a single group with JS RegExp as it does not store the capture value stack for each group (the subsequent capture re-writes the existing one, and thus, only the last capture is stored per group).

Capture the streak of comma-separated numbers and then split to get them separately. E.g. make the end of your pattern look like `((?:\s*,\s*\d+)*)` (to match 0+ sequences of `,` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces followed with 1+ digits) and then, upon a match, split with `/\s*,\s*/` and filter.

See the JS demo:

```js
var rx = /\b(GO(?:TO|SUB)|THEN)(\s*)(\d+)((?:\s*,\s*\d+)*)/gi;
var str = "100 ON ERR GOTO 10000, 30,   200, 10,800: GOSUB 20: IF A THEN 10: GOTO30: GOTO  50";
var m;
while ((m = rx.exec(str)) !== null) {
   console.log( [m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4].split(/\s*,\s*/).filter(Boolean)] );
}
```

Comment: OK thanks for the code, this is leading me in the right direction. I think I will simply detect if group4 has more than one comma in it and then remove it and append the original results with the results of another regex like `(\s*,\s*)(\d*)`